# Connecting an external camera to iPhone XI, then using it for Skype and Zoom using a smart TV as a screen

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, webcam, skype

My boss asked me this question but I think that's entirely impossible.
He wants to replicate his iphone screen on a Samsung Smart TV, then, using his Skype / Zoom / Teams app in the Iphone, call people and put the iphone on the table and let people see him from an external webcam. connected to the iphone via bluetooth or wifi. What do you think about? Thank you

Comment: Found this video about using a USB webcam with an iPad interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrPg8lNWYE0

Comment: Not exactly related but you could do the screen mirroring features mentioned in other answers, then get another iOS product (Touch, iPad, etc.) and join the meeting as another attendee, then use the other iOS product as your camera. He would just need to keep it muted and the camera turned off on the iPhone. I thought of it as I did something similar when I was teaching my MIL how to draw something and really needed TWO cameras (one for me, and one for reference item). Of course you'd also need some kind of mount/tripod/stand of some sort -- but easily solvable with all the options on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the [Apple Digital AV Adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202044) as it allows you to connect an external monitor to your iPhone/iPad device.  That would be the most efficient method.

The second method to do this would be to utilize an AppleTV  connected to the external monitor/TV.  You would then AirPlay the Zoom meeting to AppleTV.  This would meet your requirements of being wireless, but keep in mind that in an office environment where there's lots of demand for WiFi, you may see a choppy video due to network latency and dropped packets.  If possible, create a dedicated VLAN with QoS (quality of service) configured to put priority on that traffic.

A third option would be to simply get an inexpensive Mac like a Mac mini and connect the screen along with a quality webcam like the Logitech Brio or if the room is large enough, one of their "pro grade" conference web cams.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what we want to do, as I wrote we want to attach an external camera in place of the integrated one.

Comment: You're not going to find a Bluetooth webcam because the bandwidth for BT is so low.  USB is 480Mbps.  Bluetooth is 800Kbps.    That's roughly 685x more bandwidth via USB. There are WiFi webcams, but do you know of any app that can take an H.264 stream and pipe it to Zoom on iOS?  Likely custom programming.   Sometimes what you want is simply outside the realm of possibility.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I thought and the explanation I'll give to my boss. Thanks again very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of software solutions that will help you use your iPhone as a webcam. Combining that with screen sharing or HDMI connection from your Mac/Windows to TV or device like Apple TV would likely be the easiest method.

I recommend you google 'iphone webcam' for a number of good links, otherwise currently (Oct 2020), Kinoni's EpocCam, and Reincubate's Camo appear to be two very good solutions:

https://www.kinoni.com/
https://reincubate.com/camo/

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what we want to do, as I wrote we want to attach an external camera in place of the integrated one.